# Eclipse Check for redundant method calls

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a bunch of methods calling each other. The actual code is not important here, but here is an example:

```
void doStuff(){
    doMoreStuff();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
}
void doMoreStuff(){
    doEvenMoreStuff();
}
void doEvenMoreStuff(){
    // Do some stuff
}
```

As you can see, calling `doStuff()` causes `doEvenMoreStuff()` to be called twice. This isn't really a problem but it could help identify some problems and make my code cleaner. My question is, is there a way in Eclipse to check for things like this?

Comment: Do you want to know where all the method is being called ?

Comment: Yes, so it would go and highlight `doEvenMoreStuff()` in the method `doStuff()` and say something like, "Redundant method call"

Comment: Since it's legitimate to call any given method multiple times, there's really no way the IDE could identify multiple calls as "redundant".  You might have wanted to doEvenMoreStuff twice.

Comment: @CarlManaster Yes I know that, it wouldn't be like a compile warning, more like something in the Source menu. It could just check for **possible** redundant calls. Is there such a plugin?

Comment: The same thing could check for possible field setting. `x=1; x=1;` would show "Redundant field access"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know from where all the method is being called then just highlight the method shortcut is

Windows : Ctl + Shift + g

Mac : Command + Shift + g

This will show you all the occurrences of the method call.

Also Eclipse gives you warning for unused methods but nothing about redundant method. Also this is not possible if the method is public since it can be used across files and it will be too complicated.